# addSubview from different file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, class

In a game I am making, I made a class file called bomb.  In the file, I have a method called displayBomb:

```
    - (void) displayBomb
    {
        bombImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
    }
```

The method is supposed to make an image display on the screen.  In my ViewController.m file in ViewDidLoad, I have:

```
    bomb *bomb1 = [[bomb alloc] init];
    [bomb1 setValue:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forKey:@"bombImage"];
    [bomb1 displayBomb];
```

It doesn't display anything, though.  I think the problem is that I need something like `[self.view addSubview:bombImage]`.  When I put that in the ViewController.m file, it says `Use of undeclared identifier 'bombImage'`.  When I put that in bomb.m, it says `property "view" not found on object of type bomb *`.  I figure I need something like `[ViewController.view addSubview:bombImage]`, but that returns `property "view" not found on object of type ViewController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call a method on an object you don't have a reference to. Your view controller needs to know about `bombImage` or your bomb needs to know about your view controller. You could make `bombImage` a property of `bomb` and then in your view controller do this:

```
[self.view addSubview:bomb1.bombImage];
```

Edit: The typical way I'd assign an image on `bombImage` would be the following:

```
bombImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
[bombImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

Comment: In bomb.h I put `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *bombImage;`.  Then I put `[self.view addSubview:bomb1.bombImage];` in the ViewController file.  It still doesn't display the image, though.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: How would I make bomb know about the ViewController @Luke?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. What you've said in your comment should work if your image view is initialized properly - I'm not familiar with using setValue:forKey to choose an image, so I'm not sure if something's going wrong there. I would step through with a debugger and make sure that everything's getting initialized as you expect.

Comment: How else could you do it other than the setValue:forKey? @Luke

Answer (score 0):

add view parameter to your method:

```
 - (void) displayBombOnView:(UIview *)view
    {
        bombImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];

        [view addSubview:bombImage];
}
```

in viewDidLoad call method:

```
[bomb1 displayBombOnView:self.view];//or which view is on superview
```